# Macbook Air M1 terminal taking too much time to load

Tags: terminal

I am using air m1.

When I open terminal its take too much time about 10-12 sec to start.
This problem was from the beginning.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Remove/time commands in your `~/.bash_profile` if any, then see the linked Q&A. If the solutions there don't work, [edit] to explain what you've tried to reopen.

Comment: Hi @icondaemon. You’ve robbed this question on getting a honest review if the OP comes back to edit it. Your change was fine to correct some grammar, but in no way did it fix the reason why it was closed.  Reaz, if you make a substantial edit to fix this, please flag  for moderator manual review it doesn’t get voted to reopen within a day of your edit.